# Does a graphics-intensive game need a faster Internet connection than one with less intense graphics?

Tags: networking, gaming, 3d-graphics

Would we require a stronger internet connection for a more graphic demanding game?
For example:

> 4 persons play multiplayer of Counter Strike 1.6 (Which is not a very
>   graphic demanding game) on a Local Area Network with each other and
>   they enjoy a smooth, lag-free experience.
>
> The same 4 persons then decide to play multiplayer of Assassin's Creed
>   Unity (Which is indeed quite a powerful game in terms of graphics) on
>   the SAME Local Area Network.

Now my question is, would they require a more stronger connection for ACU or would they assume that since CS 1.6 is very much playable on the same LAN so the internet connectivity is good enough and they will be able to play ACU online smoothly as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would completely depend on the game (how it is internally built) - typically, the game would transfer only meta data, and the graphics are created locally, so the answer would be **'No, you don't need a better connection'**. However, each game designer is free to build his game as he likes.

What is probably more important is the amount of meta data that needs to flow around, but again, that depends on game internals that are unknown without seeing the game's code.

Answer (score 0):

No, the networking part of a game is independent of its graphics. Each game sends a different amount of data over the network, you should do some test with ACU to see if it works ok, but it doesn't depend at all on the graphics, which run locally in each computer.